# Docker can't connect to host machine on specific port

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I'm trying to setup PHP's XDebug on a official PHP image, connecting to a Windows 10 host (Docker for Windows) on port 9000. I've checked my phpinfo(), and the settings I've set show up:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug
```

No log gets written, and at someones suggestion, I did a telnet to 9000 of the host machine from within, and telnet just says connected and then nothing (which I'm guessing means communication is blocked).

Comment: Have you exposed port 9000 on that container? Does telnet give any feedback? What about to some input?

Comment: I've tried exposing port 9000 (though through a docker-compose.yml, not as an EXPOSE command in the Dockerfile). Telnet just says connected and then nothing else. What sort of input?

Comment: You do not need to expose 9000 port .. as it's Xdebug that connect to IDE and not other way around. So basically your image must allow outgoing connections on 9000 port that in turn must reach the host OS. Maybe you are using the wrong IP, maybe your IDE/editor does not listen for incoming Xdebug connections, try another port (e.g. 9001 -- in both IDE and xdebug settings). Anyway -- collect and check xdebug log to see if it even trying to connect anywhere.